# RubyMotion Pie Chart CALayer

Tags: ruby, calayer, pie-chart, rubymotion

I am trying to translate this example http://lepetit-prince.net/ios/?p=1510 into RubyMotion and neither of the 'pie slices' I create show up on screen. I am not using the for loop in the example because I am only using two 'slices' of the pie. Any ideas?

```
chart = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRect.new([60, 100], [200, 200]))
chart.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithRed(0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5)
chart.layer.cornerRadius = 100
@window.addSubview(chart)

green = 70.0
red = 30.0

red = red / 100.0 * 2.0 * Math::PI
green = green / 100 * 2.0 * Math::PI
start = 0.0

path = UIBezierPath.alloc.init
finish = start + red
sa = start - Math::PI / 2.0
ea = finish - Math::PI / 2.0
puts sa, ea
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint.new(100, 100))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint.new(100, 100), radius:100, startAngle:sa, endAngle:ea, clockwise:true)
sl = CAShapeLayer.alloc.init
sl.fillColor = UIColor.redColor
sl.path = path.CGPath
chart.layer.addSublayer(sl)

start = finish

path = UIBezierPath.alloc.init
finish = start + green
sa = start - Math::PI / 2.0
ea = finish - Math::PI / 2.0
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint.new(100, 100))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint.new(100, 100), radius:100, startAngle:sa, endAngle:ea, clockwise:true)
sl = CAShapeLayer.alloc.init
sl.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor
sl.path = path.CGPath
chart.layer.addSublayer(sl)

mask = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRect.new([0, 0], [196, 196]))
mask.layer.cornerRadius = 98
mask.center = CGPoint.new(100, 100)
mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor

chart.addSubview(mask)
```

Comment: Try moving ``@window.addSubview(chart)`` to the last line

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code to work with minor modifications.

1. The only real bug was that the fill color of a `CALayer` needs to be a `CGColor` and not a `UIColor`.  To fix that, I added `.CGColor` to do the conversion.
2. I put your code inside of `viewDidLoad` of a `ViewController`.  Since you didn't provide all of your code, I wasn't sure how you had implemented it.
3. It isn't necessary to use `CGPoint.new` and `CGRect.new` in RubyMotion.  I replaced those with simpler direct array constants, such as `[100, 100]` and `[[60, 100], [200, 200]]`.
4. I made the mask smaller so that it looked more like the original example.

Here's the full code:

**app_delegate.rb**

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    @window.rootViewController = ViewController.alloc.init
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end
```

**view_controller.rb**

```
class ViewController < UIViewController
  def viewDidLoad
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor

    chart = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame([[60, 100], [200, 200]])
    chart.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithRed(0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5)
    chart.layer.cornerRadius = 100

    green = 70.0
    red = 30.0

    red = red / 100.0 * 2.0 * Math::PI
    green = green / 100 * 2.0 * Math::PI
    start = 0.0

    path = UIBezierPath.alloc.init
    finish = start + red
    sa = start - Math::PI / 2.0
    ea = finish - Math::PI / 2.0
    puts sa, ea
    path.moveToPoint([100, 100])
    path.addArcWithCenter([100, 100], radius:100, startAngle:sa, endAngle:ea, clockwise:true)
    sl = CAShapeLayer.alloc.init
    sl.fillColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor
    sl.path = path.CGPath
    chart.layer.addSublayer(sl)

    start = finish

    path = UIBezierPath.alloc.init
    finish = start + green
    sa = start - Math::PI / 2.0
    ea = finish - Math::PI / 2.0
    path.moveToPoint([100, 100])
    path.addArcWithCenter([100, 100], radius:100, startAngle:sa, endAngle:ea, clockwise:true)
    sl = CAShapeLayer.alloc.init
    sl.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor.CGColor
    sl.path = path.CGPath
    chart.layer.addSublayer(sl)

    mask = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame([[0, 0], [100, 100]])
    mask.layer.cornerRadius = 50 
    mask.center = [100, 100]
    mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor

    chart.addSubview(mask)
    view.addSubview(chart)
  end
end
```